# Magento 2.2 - order confirmation/order edit - rounded bundled product qty

Tags: magento2, product, orders, bundle

I use decimal qty for some products.
If product type is simple order confirmation email sends qty correctly in decimal eg. 1.05 m2 Unfortunately if same product is part of bundle qty is rounded down.
Same issue is in order edit. After order is edited via admin qty is rouded.

Where to fix qty rounding or does somebody has some workaround?

Comment: Can you please openaticket here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/?